# The value of the following series is S. Find pi

Tags: sequences-and-series, infinite-product

$$S=\sqrt \frac{1}{2}\sqrt {\frac{1}{2}+ \frac{1}{2}\sqrt \frac{1}{2}}\sqrt {\frac{1}{2}+ \frac{1}{2}\sqrt {\frac{1}{2}+ \sqrt \frac{1}{2}}} . . .$$

Answer is 2. Please help. I tried taking log but it was not fruitful.

Comment: Think about the cosine half-angle formula.

Comment: Thanks a lot Ron. Great help! :)

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1081519/calculate-sqrt-frac12-times-sqrt-frac12-frac12-sqrt-frac